# Unable to parse Lexical to HTML

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, lexicaljs

I have a Lexical editor that needs to be serialized into html so that I can embed it in an email template.

I keep running into the following error when using the `$generateHtmlFromNodes` function:

```
Error: Unable to find an active editor state.
State helpers or node methods can only be
used synchronously during the callback of editor.update() or editorState.read().
```

My Editor component takes one prop, the editorRef of type LexicalEditor, which ensures I have access to the editor from the parent, where I would like to handle the serialization and sending of the email.

Editor.tsx:

```js
interface EditorProps {
  editorRef: React.MutableRefObject<LexicalEditor>;
}

export const Editor = (props: EditorProps) => {
  const initialConfig = {
    namespace: 'MyEditor',
    editable: true,
    nodes: [ImageNode],
    theme: <myTheme>,
    onError(error) {
      throw error;
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative rounded-sm border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow-sm">
      <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
        <Toolbar />
        <ImagesPlugin />

        <RichTextPlugin
          contentEditable={
            <ContentEditable
              autoCorrect
              className="min-h-[450px] resize-none overflow-hidden text-ellipsis py-[15px] px-2.5 outline-none"
            />
          }
          placeholder={null}
        />
        <OnChangePlugin
          onChange={(editorState, editor) => (props.editorRef.current = editor)}
        />
        <HistoryPlugin />
      </LexicalComposer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My parent component:

```js
export default function EmailClient() {
  const editorRef = useRef<LexicalEditor>();

  const handleSendEmail = () => {
    const editor = editorRef.current;
    const editorState = editor.getEditorState();
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(editorState);
    console.log('jsonString', jsonString);
    const htmlString = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
    console.log(htmlString);
  };
  return (
        <Editor editorRef={editorRef} />
          <Button
            text="send"
            function={handleSendEmail}
          />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging on the [Github issues](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/issues/2325#issuecomment-1193982187) I found a solution which is contrary to the examples in the lexical documentation.

It is necessary to wrap the `$generateHtmlFromNodes` function in an `editor.update` function as follows:

```js
editor.update(() => {
   const htmlString = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
});
```

Comment: All `$` prefixed functions on Lexical can only be called inside certain callbacks: https://lexical.dev/docs/faq#why-does-lexical-use-the--prefix-in-the-name-of-many-of-the-functions