# Parsing Lexical to HTML gives empty string

Tags: html, lexical, lexical-editor

I am using a lexical editor and want to convert lexical data to HTML **on click of a button**.

After referring from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807767/unable-to-parse-lexical-to-html), I am using `$generateHtmlFromNodes` and wrapping it inside `editor.update` function.

My code:

```
import { $generateHtmlFromNodes } from '@lexical/html';

document.getElementById("export-html").addEventListener("click", () => {
    editor.update(() => {
      const htmlString = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
      console.log('htmlString', htmlString);
    });
  })
```

The output I am receiving:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmVBE.png)

Expecting a proper HTML output in string format. I checked [Serialization](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization) as well.